# Not able to enable auto deploy on heroku with git repo

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

Whenever I'm trying to deploy my node.js application with connecting to my own git repo and try to enable auto deploy it throws this error

Item could not be updated:
Unknown Error. Please contact support.

When I try to contact support it says

There is no way to support contact for free applications. Every time it shows Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community.  For all programming related questions related to particular languages or frameworks, please visit the Stack Overflow community. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help from fellow Heroku users by searching thousands of previous questions or asking your own. For all questions related to the Heroku platform or specific Heroku products, please visit the Salesforce Stack Exchange community.

Is there any way to turn on auto-deploy from CLI or what I can do in this case

Comment: The error literally says "please contact support", so: did you?

Comment: Yes, but as I'm using a free Heroku account it says search StackOverflow to get your question solved for free accounts

Comment: there are a million errors on heroku, but I've never seen one that actually tells you to contact support, so: contact support anyway?

Comment: There is no way to support contact for free applications. Every time it shows

```Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community.

For all programming related questions related to particular languages or frameworks, please visit the Stack Overflow community. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help from fellow Heroku users by searching thousands of previous questions or asking your own. For all questions related to the Heroku platform or specific Heroku products, please visit the Salesforce Stack Exchange community.```

Comment: Don't tell me, tell everyone by editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error. Incognito mode solved the issue for me.
If you are looking for other ways, check out this official [page](https://help.heroku.com/A1BZM6QC/why-do-i-see-item-could-not-be-updated-retrieved-unknown-error-on-the-dashboard)